# How to use CassiniDev.Lib without the timeout?

Tags: c#, cassini-dev

I am using the CassiniDev.Lib4 DLL and recognized that the server stops responding after a certain amount of time.

Looking at the code in CassiniServer.cs I could see that a timeout of 60 seconds is set:

`_server = new Server(port, virtualPath, applicationPath, ipAddress, hostname, 60000);`

How can I avoid any timeout of the server? And why is there a timeout?

EDIT: Fiddler tells me:
`HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 09:18:38.367`
`The socket connection to localhost failed. 
Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte 127.0.0.1:1278`

EDIT 2: I'm not sure anymore, that it has to do with an implemented timeout, because I kept time and can't recognize a 60 seconds time window. Sometimes the server didn't respond after 40 seconds after the last click. Or could it be, that a cached website was loaded and the last click didn't trigger a request?

I am really looking forward to your hints!

Best regards,

KB

Comment: Timeouts are usually because of a request taking too long. What are you doing that makes the server TimeOut?

Comment: The timeout is when I do nothing on my website, means when I doesn't click/browse. It does **not** seem to be a pending request timeout.

Comment: I am not familiar with CassiniDev, do you at one point Open a connection and choose not to close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick walkaround I uncommented the code of DecrementRequestCount() and IncrementRequestCount() in Server.cs. I think there [still](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/workitem/14100) is a bug in CassiniDev.Lib4.
Cassini now seems to run properly without stopping responding.

I am sorry, that I didn't had more time to dive deeper into this, but I would appreciate any hints or fixes for this.