# CassiniDev Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cassini, cassini-dev

I've been testing out CassiniDev server for a project I'm working on currently, and I've been so impressed with this!

Big well done to the guy(s) who made this!

I do seem to have a small problem though, and wondered if anyone else has encountered it and managed to resolve it...

I'm using the the CassiniDev-lib.dll in my WinForms C# (Net3.5) project to host my web server, I start the server fine with the following command:

```
_server.StartServer("C:\\www\\host\\test", 32500, "/", "");
```

I can navigate around my ASPX web pages with no problems in the forms WebBrowser control, but if I leave the Form running for a few minutes and return to use it the server doesnt respond?

The server is still in "started" mode, but if I refresh the current page or try navigating to a different one I receive the error:

> This program cannot display the webpage

If I stop the server manually, then restart, it works again for a few minutes, then repeats the same error.

IIS is not running in the background or anything, tried diferrent Ports but still seems to happen.

Does anyone have any ideas/experience with this cool little webserver?

Thanks all!

Comment: Maybe answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115851/how-to-use-cassinidev-lib-without-the-timeout